# How to resolve this facelets warning message

Tags: jsf, facelets

What does this error message mean? What values should be provided to get rid of this warning?

```
15:10:58,024 WARNING [component] facelets.RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUIL
D_BEFORE_RESTORE is set to 'true' but facelets.BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE is set
to 'false' or unset. To use facelets.RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEF
ORE_RESTORE you must also set facelets.BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE to 'true'!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `web.xml` file, it seems that you have this parameter defined:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

So as stated by the warning message, just add:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Another solution is to remove the first parameter from `web.xml`...

Comment: I don't have that parameter defined, anyways I will try to set the 2nd parameter and see if it goes away

Comment: @Joshua Eventually, you can also set the first parameter (`RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE`) to `false`...

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this functionality is not really useful and could be dangerous (it broke the Ajax re-render in my case).

I suppress the warning by adding this in my web.xml :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Broken link. Looks like his blog has been removed :-/